# Visualizing closeness of multi-variable data

Tags: multivariate-analysis

I'm hoping to get some direction in how to get a visual feeling for some data.  The independent variables consist of 4 tuples of positive integers, such as (1, 4, 3, 100) and my outputs are each continuous positive numbers. In particular, I'm hoping to visually see if there are tendencies in how the 4 tuples clump together to produce similar output.  In other words, does the output of (2, 4, 3, 99) behave similarly to (1, 4, 3, 99) since the two vectors are "close"?

Any visual and/or numerical measurements to get a sense of this would be appreciated.

Comment: Think of the 1D case and extrapolate.  If you had a single independent variable and a single output, how would you visualise trends in the output for similar input?

Comment: In that case, I would just use a scatterplot, pairing each (x,y).  And, if my inputs were tuples, then I could use (x,y,z) where the (x,y) were my independent variables and z were my continuous output variable.  But, with a 4 tuple?

Comment: So you need some way to reduce your dimensions.  Try TSNE for this kind of visualisation.  That's what is designed for.  It will collapse your 4D into 2D (or 3, but 2 is best) and plot them while retaining natural distances.

Comment: There are many techniques commonly used in spatial and geographic analysis (applied in two and three dimensions) that are readily adapted to higher dimensions.  For instance, you could display empirical variograms; compute statistics like Moran's I; compute generalized "Local Indicators of Spatial Association"; perform Geographically Weighted Regression; *etc*.  The techniques vary according to what you want to learn and exactly how you wish to characterize it.

Comment: @neuroguy123 This is what I was looking for.  Would you mind changing your comment to an answer so that I can accept it?